# Disable editing cursor in QListView

Tags: android, qt, listview

I'm trying to make a program on android with Qt and c++. I know that it's not the best way but it's allowing me to make some useful apps without learning Java ...
I have a problem with the QListView widget, I would like to disable the editing cursor, exactly this one :
[Cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAqiq.jpg)

I've already set the editTrigger by this command : `setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);`

But the cursor is still showing.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this problem specific to Android? Or can you reproduce it on Windows/Mac too?

Comment: Sorry for the time I took to answer you. I got arround the problem by using a listWidget.
But the problem is specific to android.